# Reference Request for problems in Serre's text

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, p-adic-number-theory

So, I am self studying from Serre's book "A Course in Arithmetic" and finding this book a little terse to go through on my own and as if the theory isn't difficult enough to grasp,there are no problems in the book to check what I've learned in the theory.
After spending countless hours online searching for problems, I have finally decided to post my query here.

I have already googled and found a text for Modular Forms, it would be great if I can get other recommendations for problems in topics: **padic numbers** (includes analysis and topology of $\mathbb{Z_{p}}$ and $\mathbb{Q_{p}}$, hensel's lemma and applications), **Hilbert Symbols and Quadratic Forms**(includes Wiit's theorems, representation of an element by a quadratic form, quadratic forms over the field of padic numbers).

Can someone here suggest me appropriate resources based (more or less) on the theory given in Serre?

Comment: Do you know koblitz, p adic numbers, p adic analysis and zeta functions ? Also Scharlu: Quadratic and Hermitian forms.

Comment: I just checked both of them and surely the first reference contains lots of standard problems on padic numbers which is exactly what I was looking for. but the second text you suggested doesn't. Thank you so much!

Comment: For $p$-adic numbers, Schikhof's *Ultrametric Calculus* and Serre's *Local Fields*.